stream reasoning on home alarms on edge devices
I'm working on some home automation SW for a Security usecase  I imagine to have ultimately an ontology with different sources of information:

camera(s)
microphones
burglary
alarm
other sensing equipment's

The events I would like to detect, using a mix of image / sound recognition etc. are:
burglary

my son coming home with guests (!)
window break
fire
dog barking
etc.

And ultimately I have a list of actions:

warn or call police
call my neighbour
call my brother that lives in the same street
warn or call the fire brigade
call RSPC (animal protection agency)
etc.

Ultimately I would like to build a mini-reasoning structure able to suggest different actions in relationship to different input, taking into account that false positive exist and need to be avoided (i.e. offering some level of cross-checking).
Potentially this would take place on an edge device of some type.
I would be interested to study similar projects and to get some ideas.
The key parts that I'm less comfortable with are:

how to update my reasoning structure  with streaming data from sensors and alarms?
Should I use only in-memory components?
Are streaming solutions able to offer edge-based in-memory solutions but offering reasoning capabilities comparable with ontologies?

Suggestions / ideas welcome!

RDFox is commercial and it does not really have a community edition. You can download and evaluation license which is valid for 1 month. GraphDB from Ontotext does have community edition and it supports some of the same reasoning capabilities as RDFox. For your purposes GraphDB is likely sufficient.

thanks @henriette Hamse.  On the other hand more than the tool to use I think I need some guidance on how to do it.  Would you be so kind to point me to some existing project / demo that could help me?


Create ontology. 2. Import ontology into GraphDB/RDFox. This should provide rules that can act in your data.


To build the ontology you can translate UML to OWL which I describe on my blog.

I've update the question.  Thanks for your help, but my issue are more in the direction posed at the end, not so much on how to build a generic ontology. Thanks for helping to clarify my thinking.
